# How can I use odoo login api to external application like postman and java?

Tags: java, api, odoo-13

I want to hit login api from `postman` or java and the error generating bad `csrf` token.

Have any solution to fix this issue or we disabled `csrf` token?

Comment: would you care to post any code?

Comment: Please provide more details like what you have tried and also check if there is db_name added to the config file means you should have only one database accessible at a time

Answer (score 0):

Read the [**documentation on external API's**](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/developer/misc/api/odoo.html), use this snippet to **test out connection** to your **Odoo instance**:

```
final XmlRpcClient client = new XmlRpcClient();

final XmlRpcClientConfigImpl start_config = new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl();
start_config.setServerURL(new URL("https://demo.odoo.com/start"));
final Map<String, String> info = (Map<String, String>)client.execute(
    start_config, "start", emptyList());

final String url = info.get("host"),
              db = info.get("database"),
        username = info.get("user"),
        password = info.get("password");
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you must create an application to connect using rpc request. However, if you want to test it in dev environment, you can disable the csrf token in route.
According to this website http://vauxoo.github.io/odoo/reference/http.html, there is csrf parameter that can be set to false in the route.

Answer (score 0):

Try jsonrpc web authentication api  "/web/session/authenticate" with type json. I am working on odoo framework mobile api connection. Its working.